# Create a function to find the Max & Min

Tags: c++, function, variables, initialization

```
float inputArray(int &size,float &inputdata,float array1[]);
float findMaxMin(int &size,float &max,float &min,float array1[]);
void displayMenu (float &max, float &min);



using namespace std;

int main() {
    int size;   // Variable designated for the number of elements the user wishes to allocate
    float inputdata; // Designated for temporarily storing the user input for the array
    float max;          // Variable designated for the maximum value within the array
    float min;          // Variable designated for the minimum value within the array
    float array1[size]; // Array consisting of a specified number of elements by user

inputArray(size,inputdata,array1);
findMaxMin(size,max,min,array1);
displayMenu(max,min);



return 0;

}



/******************************Input Array Data*****************************/
float inputArray(int &size,float &inputdata,float array1[]){


  cout << "Type in the number of elements you wish to utilize" << endl;
    cin >> size;        // User specifies number of elements to be allocated



    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        cout << "Type in value for element " << x << " and Press [ENTER] "
             << endl;
        cin >> inputdata;
        array1[x] = inputdata;

        }

}
/****************************************************************************/




/*************************Determination of Max & Min*************************/

float findMaxMin(int &size,float &max,float &min,float array1[]){

//The min and max variables are given the value of the first element of array1.

    max=min=array1[0];  


    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            if (min > array1[x]) {
                min = array1[x];
            }
            if (max < array1[x]) {
                max = array1[x];
            }
    }

}

/*****************************************************************************/





/*********************************Menu Screen*********************************/
/**The Menu Screen will tell the user that the data collection is complete and 
will prompt the user to input an integer to trigger the display of the desired 
output**/


void displayMenu (float &max, float &min){


        char menuInput; // Variable designated to store user input for the menu
        bool inputTester;


        do {
            cout << "\n\n\t\tYour Data Has Been Collected"
                    "\n\t\tTo View Maximum of Data Set Enter.......\t 9"
                    "\n\t\tTo View Minimum of Data Set Enter.......\t 0"
                 << endl;
            cin >>menuInput;


                            switch(menuInput){
                            case('9'):
                                    cout<<"Maximum is "<<max<<endl;
                                    inputTester=true;
                                    break;

                            case('0'):
                                    cout<<"Minimum is "<<min<<endl;
                                    inputTester=true;
                                    break;

                            default:
                                cout<<"Please Enter a Valid Input"<<endl;
                                inputTester=false;
                                break;

                                }
        }

        while (inputTester==false);

}
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is: Prompt user to input float numbers in console; – Create a function to find the max/min number of the array; – Create a function to display the max and min depending on what command (‘0’ or ‘9’) is being typed by the user in console. But I keep getting an error and I'm stuck.

Comment: You mean re-write [std::minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)?

Answer (score 2):

```
    int size;  // <---- here
    float inputdata;
    float max;
    float min;
    float array1[size];  // <--- and here
```

Your variable `int size` is uninitialized and you use it to allocate `float array1` of unknown number of elements; Later you are trying to write to this array assuming that the number of available elements is equal to user input (which is not). That's why your stack is corrupted and you might get seg fault when returning from main. You should use dynamic allocation with `operator new` or just use appropriate C++ container for this job (like `std::vector`).

Advice: compile your programs with `-Wall -Werror` flags. Compiler will tell you about uninitialized variables, no return statements in the functions and similar.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get a `min` and `max` from an array is with the [std::minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) provided by the `<algorithm>` header. To write a function to return a `minmax` `std::pair`, you could do:

```
/* returns <min, max> pair from arr of nelem */
std::pair<float*, float*> minmaxfloat (float *arr, size_t nelem)
{
    return std::minmax_element (arr, arr + nelem);
}
```

A short example could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

/* returns <min, max> pair from arr of nelem */
std::pair<float*, float*> minmaxfloat (float *arr, size_t nelem)
{
    return std::minmax_element (arr, arr + nelem);
}

int main (void) {

    float arr[] = { 5, 4, 6, 3, 7, 2, 8, 1, 9 };
    float min, max;
    /* create minmax pair from call to minmaxfloat() */
    std::pair<float*, float*> p1 = minmaxfloat (arr, sizeof arr/sizeof *arr);

    min = *p1.first;    /* assign min */
    max = *p1.second;   /* assign max */

    std::cout << "min: " << min << " max: " << max << '\n';
}
```

(**note:** the `std::pair` will consist of two-pointers to the `min` and `max` elements within your array)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/floatminmax
min: 1 max: 9
```

It beats coming up with your own. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Good answer. Note: C++17 allows `auto [pmin, pmax] = minmaxfloat (arr, sizeof arr/sizeof *arr);`.

Comment: Yes, that was really neat, but my suse box only has C++14 (interesting, it will let me do that with C++1z as well). Not knowing what the OP had available, I just went ahead and used a full `std::pair` so they didn't run into any compiler problems.

Comment: And this is what I would have done too (with a note that C++17 allows the syntax above) *thumbsup*